# Can't mount my sdcard rw

Tags: sd-card, mount

I really messed up my HTC Desire today. I need to copy some files to the sdcard, but my Android phone won't let me mount the SD card with write access.

Here's what I've done in short:

(boot to recovery, phone rooted)

```
$ sudo -i
#./adb root
adbd is already running as root
./adb shell
~ # mount -o rw /dev/block/mmcblk0p1 /sdcard/
~ # cd sdcard/
/sdcard # ls
ls: ./internal: I/O error
/sdcard # touch test.txt
touch: test.txt: Read-only file system
/sdcard #
```

/sdcard/internal is a folder I created and copied some files to before the sdcard ceased to be writteable.

From now on I can't do anything, my system is down, It won't boot, and I can't copy a ROM to the SD-Card.

Comment: I/O error as shown, sounds like a badly damaged sd card... best to ditch it and get a new one instead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to format `/sdcard/` via the recovery, but it would do nothing, contrary to what it logs.

So finally i've formatted it via `newfs_msdos` (`/system/` needs to be mounted, the command is located at `/system/bin/newfs_msdos` ) :

```
/system/bin # ./newfs_msdos -F 32 /dev/block/mmcblk0p1
./newfs_msdos: warning, /dev/block/mmcblk0p1 is not a character device
./newfs_msdos: Skipping mount checks
/dev/block/mmcblk0p1: 5992960 sectors in 93640 FAT32 clusters (32768 bytes/cluster)
bps=512 spc=64 res=32 nft=2 mid=0xf0 spt=16 hds=4 hid=0 bsec=5994496 bspf=732 rdcl=2 infs=1 bkbs=2
/system/bin # ./newfs_msdos -F 32 /dev/block/mmcblk0p1
./newfs_msdos: warning, /dev/block/mmcblk0p1 is not a character device
./newfs_msdos: Skipping mount checks
/dev/block/mmcblk0p1: 5992960 sectors in 93640 FAT32 clusters (32768 bytes/cluster)
bps=512 spc=64 res=32 nft=2 mid=0xf0 spt=16 hds=4 hid=0 bsec=5994496 bspf=732 rdcl=2 infs=1 bkbs=2
```

and then my sdcard was fine, I could write on it and use it via USB. I guess it was somewhat corrupted.

Comment: Could be worth noting that there might be a reason it got corrupted in the first place; don't rely on it for important information in the future :)

Comment: Yeah, I think it's effectively corrupted. now I had some other trouble, and it won't even detect it :/ . The point is, my laptop has no problem with it.

Comment: Hate to say it, but it might be your SD card slot in your phone as well :'(

Comment: erf, haven't thought of that. Poor old Desire, you were such a good mate ...

Comment: update: I have done some research and my symptons looks like something called "usb brick", I'll seek through it

Answer (score 1):

You should try this command to remount as rw (read-write):

```
mount -o remount,rw /mnt/sdcard
```

Comment: remount doesn't work!